# Given this css, why isn't this text and images aligning vertically?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have the following text and images and I want to make them align vertically middle together.

Here is my html

```
    <span class="fav">
       <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/star_grey.png">
       <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/mail.png">
       <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/clone.png">
       <span class="myText">2</span>
       <img src="/Content/Images/Icons/information_red.png" />
     </span>
```

Here is my css

```
.fav {
     vertical-align: middle;
}

.numberOfDelivs
{
   background-color:#4cb3e9;
   border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family:tahoma, arial, 'sans-serif';
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size: 10px;
   padding: 3px 6px;
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
```

}

but as per the screenshot and the text (that shows the #2) is still shows up below all of the images

![enter image description here][1]

Any suggestions on how i can get that text that is in the "myText" class moved up so it lines up with the images?

I tried adding margin or negative margin-top and various padding options but none seem to have any effect.

Comment: How does the `.numberOfDelivs` CSS selector apply to the posted markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to align the children of the span, not the span itself.

Use `.fav > *` for your selector.